# Bootstrap well is not covering the content

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would try to make the image align with the border line. But I cannot figure out. (As the image below) And I am not sure why the well is not covering my content. Not sure what is the problem. Hope you can help.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated!

```css
.img-responsive {
    left: 15px;
    z-index: 14;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="well">

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>arbitror cernantur amet multos ullamco dolore ad philosophari a ad est arbitrantur qui distinguantur illum graviterque laboris quis quorum non quid consectetur doctrina instituendarum esse sempiternum ad ad coniunctione possumus a ingeniis sint irure illum</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this little correction does the work

```
<div class="container">
<div class="well">
<div class="row">


<div class="col-md-6">
<img class="img-responsive" src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<p>arbitror cernantur amet multos ullamco dolore ad philosophari a ad est arbitrantur qui distinguantur illum graviterque laboris quis quorum non quid consectetur doctrina instituendarum esse sempiternum ad ad coniunctione possumus a ingeniis sint irure illum</p>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

and why are you using this css ?

```
.img-responsive {
    left: 15px;
    z-index: 14;
    position: absolute;
}
```

[image: image example]

I added some little changes as per your comment 
add this to your css

```
<style>
  .div-img-padLftZero{
    padding-left:0px;
  }

  </style>
```

then make your code like this

```
<div class="container">
<div class="well">
<div class="row">


<div class="col-md-6 div-img-padLftZero">
<img class="img-responsive" src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<p>arbitror cernantur amet multos ullamco dolore ad philosophari a ad est arbitrantur qui distinguantur illum graviterque laboris quis quorum non quid consectetur doctrina instituendarum esse sempiternum ad ad coniunctione possumus a ingeniis sint irure illum</p>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Now it is left aligned as you desired 
[image: left aligned to well]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, actually i want to make the image align left with the border line (like the image above). That why i added the css.

Comment: i would like to give you some-tip first of all don't use position absolute and z-index and left:15px  , you can add a class and use padding-left:0px just in the col-md-6 in which you are using the img add a new class like div-img-padzero{padding-left:0px;}

Comment: Anyway, that's nearly what I was trying to do. I will accept your answer! Thanks a lot!